# How to format a regex

Tags: python, regex, python-3.4

I am trying to make a Warning waver which can look for known warnings in a log file.

The warnings in the waving file are copied directly from the log file during a review of the warnings.

The mission here is to make it as simple as possible. But i found that directly copying was a bit problematic due to that fact that the warnings could contain absolute paths.

So I added a "tag" which could be inserted into a warning which the system should look for. The whole string would then look like this.

```
WARNING:HDLParsers:817 - ":RE[.*]:/modules/top/hdl_src/top.vhd" Line :RE[.*]: Choice . is not a locally static expression.
```

The tag is **:RE[*Insert RegEx here*]:**. 
In the above warning string there are two of these tags which I am trying to find using Python3 regex tool. And my pattern is the following:

```
(:RE\[.*\]\:)
```

See [RegEx101](https://regex101.com/r/qC6dT6/1) for reference

My problem with the above is that, when there are two tags in my string it finds only one result extended from the first to the last tag. how do i setup the regex so it will find each tag ?

Regards

Comment: don't be greedy, `(:RE\[.*?\]\:)`, https://regex101.com/r/qC6dT6/2 .

Comment: Are you using `re.findall` or `re.match`?

Comment: Well, it depends on what can be inside `[]`. If there can be no `[` or `]`, use a negated class: [`:RE\[[^[\]]*\]\:`](https://regex101.com/r/eY6zX1/1) with `re.findall`. Have a look at [the demo](https://ideone.com/ulo2Sn). However, I guess you need the lazy dot matching here.

Comment: @Avinash Raj - Works in regex 101. though not in Python3 re.search.

Comment: @ppperry - i am using re.search. need the indexes

Comment: @stribizhev i can have all regular expressions between the []

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `re.findall` with the following regex that **assumes that the regular expression inside the square brackets spans from `:RE[` up to the `]` that is followed by `]`**:

```
:RE\[.*?]:
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uB4lM0/1). The `.*?` matches 0 or more characters other than a newline but as few as possible. See [rexegg.com description of a lazy quantifier solution](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#lazy_solution):

> The lazy `.*?` guarantees that the quantified dot only matches as many characters as needed for the rest of the pattern to succeed.

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/fork/CsBk76)

```
import re
p = re.compile(r':RE\[.*?]:')
test_str = "# Even more commments\nWARNING:HDLParsers:817 - \":RE[.*]:/modules/top/hdl_src/cpu_0342.vhd\" Line :RE[.*]: Choice . is not a locally static expression."
print(p.findall(test_str))
```

If you need to get the contents between the `[` and `]`, use a capturing group so that `re.findall` could extract just those contents:

```
p = re.compile(r':RE\[(.*?)]:')
```

See [another demo](https://ideone.com/SktLd2)

To obtain indices, use [`re.finditer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.finditer) (see [this demo](https://ideone.com/BEO0Hy)):

> **`re.finditer(pattern, string, flags=0)`**
>   Return an iterator yielding match objects over all non-overlapping matches for the `RE` pattern in string. The string is scanned left-to-right, and matches are returned in the order found. Empty matches are included in the result unless they touch the beginning of another match.

```
p = re.compile(r':RE\[(.*?)]:')
print([x.start(1) for x in p.finditer(test_str)])
```